# js: templating engine for {% block include %}-style templating

Tags: javascript, html, underscore.js, templating

Currently working on a project in backbone.js, which leverages Underscore as a templating engine. AFAIK, underscore doesn't let you do template inheritance in the style of `{% block whatever %}` or `{{ include 'whatever.html }}`

Is there a good templating library out there that will give me this kind of block inheritance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My 2 preferred templating engines are [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) (which is pretty powerful) and [LinkedIn's Dust.JS](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs) (which I'm still newbie, but I believe it has support for blocks/partials).

Also, check this out: http://garann.github.com/template-chooser
It may help you!